# C#: Convert http://www.google.com to google.com

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I would like to convert a URL like this: `http://www.google.com` to this `google.com`. So if the format of the URL is like this http://google.com it will be converted to this `google.com`

I need to determine if two urls are the same no matter the format of the URL. Is there a way to do this. I am using the Uri library in C# but the host value is different for `http://www.google.com` and `http://google.com`

Comment: `www.google.com` and `google.com` *are* different. It's not just a matter of formatting. One just happens to redirect to the other.

Comment: What dtb said. There are even instructions on how to use a 301 Redirect to force the non-www to go to the www:  http://www.stepforth.com/resources/web-marketing-knowledgebase/non-www-redirect/

Comment: Note that "domain.com" and "www.domain.com" do not have to show the same website...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Uri` class to parse URIs.

Example: [Get just the domain name from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154167/c-get-just-the-domain-name-from-a-url)

You can extract more than the host name, too. Here is a full list of properties you can get from a `Uri` instance: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri_properties(v=VS.71).aspx