# Get the host name from url without www or extension in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url, hostname

Hello i need a way to find out the host part of an url , i've tried

```
Request.Url.Host.Split('.')
```

but it doesn't work with url like this:

sub.sub.domain.com

or

www.domain.co.uk

since you can have a variable number of dots before and after the domain

i need to get only "domain"

Answer (score 0):

Check out the second answer at [Get just the domain name from a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2154167/get-just-the-domain-name-from-a-url)

I checked the pastebin link; it's active.  I didn't test the code myself, but if it outputs as he describes, you can .split() from there.

Comment: I should also mention for clarity: in the case of www.domain.co.uk, domain.co.uk IS the full domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to be totally flexibel, you need to make a list of all possible top-level-domains, and try to remove those, with dot, from the end of your string, resulting in

```
www.domain
```

or

```
sub.sub.domain
```

Then take the last characters after the last dot.